# Unknown large number outside raster proximity layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity

I am using QGIS and created a raster proximity layer, values outside of the fixed distance are coming up with the value 65,535.

I created a binary raster layer for the presence of peat soil (1) and the absence of peat soil (0). I then used Raster-->Raster Analysis-->Proximity. I have a fixed distance for the proximity (1000m). The parameters I have used can be seen in the picture below.

[image: Proximity Parameters]

The output seems normal for values within 1000m. But pixels beyond 1000m have the same fixed value of 65,535.

[image: Layer Symbology]

Any ideas where this number has come from? I have tried changing some of the parameters e.g. georef to pixel, changing distance, but the number 65,535 remains the same.

As I am still quite new to using QGIS so I imagine I might be missing something. However, reading other forums I haven't found any similar questions.

Comment: Does the raster look about right? How does the histogram look?

Comment: All the values in the histogram are clustered between 0-1000, but the upper end goes up to 65535. But seemingly the values in the histogram look correct. The raster also looks correct, bar from having a 65535 value.

Comment: 65535 is the max value for an 16 bit unsigned integer. Can you set nodata to 65535, or recalculate them to some other value if they bother you?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that! Its not much of an issue as I am reclassifying anyway but I just wanted to know where this number came from. Would 65535 be put in any pixel not specified by the proximity raster?